# Source code of Gallery App Android

Tags: android

I need a source code of full Android Gallery App I don't want to compile I need it to create a project so I want it to be legal not stolen, I found the CM Gallery App on github but its too old (since 2007)..Can anyone get me that?

Comment: Don't know why u vote down but am requesting help..

Comment: This is very clearly a request for an off-site resource. The only way to answer it is to give you source code. That's not what SO is about, and it's explicitly off-topic in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

Clone the official repository.

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery
```

There is also this one

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2
```

Comment: @user4905906 clone the git repository

Comment: This is project created by AOSP build system not by Android studio or eclipse am facing many errors thanks for the help